# non blocking tcp client socket in ruby failed

Tags: ruby, networking

Trying to create a TCP socket in a non-blocking manner, but it failed. Any idea?

```
$ ruby nonblock_sock.rb 
/home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:1207:in `__connect_nonblock': Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block (IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable)
    from /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:1207:in `connect_nonblock'
    from nonblock_sock.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code snippet

```
#not working yet, 
require 'socket'

socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0) 
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(80, 'localhost') 
socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
require 'socket'
socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0) 
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(80, '127.0.0.1')  #this
socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
```

If I recall correctly, one needs to pass the IP instead of hostname(`localhost`) while [creating address](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-pack_sockaddr_in).
With this, `connect_nonblock` should raise `EINPROGRESS` where it is connecting in non-blocking manner in background which I think we can check with `IO.select` later.

**Edit**:
`IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable` is raised as expected. `connect_nonblock` leaves the connection establishment process for background and raises it.

You should be handling it like this:

```
begin
  socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS 
  IO.select(nil, [socket]) #wait for socket to be writable
  begin
    socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
  rescue Errno::EISCONN
    #=> This means connection to remote host has established successfully.
    socket.write("stuff")
  end
end
```

Comment: Changing `localhost1` to `127.0.0.1` got the same error.  Thx.

Comment: that is intended. my bad. just read your error carefully again. updated my answer. Look in edit section.

Comment: Thanks @kiddorails it helps!